# Pandas update column from values in another column, but manipulate values before updating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have two DataFrames:

df1:

```
           avg_temp total_precipitation
date                                   
2020-03-01      5.8                 0.2
2020-03-02      3.4                   0
2020-03-03      4.8                   0
2020-03-04      2.2                   0
2020-03-05      1.4                   0
2020-03-06      3.7                   0
2020-03-07        7                   0
2020-03-08      9.3                   0
2020-03-09      NaN                 NaN
2020-03-10      NaN                 NaN
2020-03-11      NaN                 NaN
2020-03-12      NaN                 NaN
2020-03-13      NaN                 NaN
2020-03-14      3.6                   0
2020-03-15      NaN                 NaN
2020-03-16      NaN                 NaN
```

and df2:

```
            min_temp  max_temp  precipitation_probability
date                                                     
2020-03-15       8.0       8.0                       0.24
2020-03-16      -2.0       9.0                       0.16
```

I need to do the following: If there are any set of rows where the `date` columns match, replace the column `avg_temp` of dataframe `df1` with `(df2["min_temp"]+df2["max_temp"])/2` of the corresponding row from `df2`.

I have tried the following code:

```
df1["avg_temp"] = np.where(df1["date"] == df2["date"], (df2["min_temp"]+df2["max_temp"])/2, df1["avg_temp"])
```

However, since `df1` and `df2` have different number of rows, and their indexes(the `date` column) don't match, this is not feasable.

Additionally, using `df1.update(df2, inplace=True)` would also not work since I need to update column `avg_temp` with the average of columns `min_temp` and `max_temp`

Would there be a way to update a column after manipulating and combining columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with some preprocessing - added new column of averages and `rename` column:

```
df22 = (df2.assign(avg_temp = (df2["min_temp"]+df2["max_temp"])/2)
           .rename(columns={'precipitation_probability':'total_precipitation'}))

df1.update(df22)
print (df1)
            avg_temp  total_precipitation
date                                     
2020-03-01       5.8                 0.20
2020-03-02       3.4                 0.00
2020-03-03       4.8                 0.00
2020-03-04       2.2                 0.00
2020-03-05       1.4                 0.00
2020-03-06       3.7                 0.00
2020-03-07       7.0                 0.00
2020-03-08       9.3                 0.00
2020-03-09       NaN                  NaN
2020-03-10       NaN                  NaN
2020-03-11       NaN                  NaN
2020-03-12       NaN                  NaN
2020-03-13       NaN                  NaN
2020-03-14       3.6                 0.00
2020-03-15       8.0                 0.24
2020-03-16       3.5                 0.16
```